# Why can't GetType().BaseClass find the base class?

Tags: c#, generics, types

Edit: its my fault as there was another `Foo` definition lurking around that made me confused with `Foo<>` definition.

In the below code, `Foo` is a base class of `Bar` right?

Then why compiler underlines the `.BaseType` part and says "the given expression is never of the provided (Form1.Foo) type"?

```
    // has 1 virtual method
    class Foo<T> : IList<T>
    {
        ...
    }

    // overrides 1 method from Foo
    class Bar : Foo<float>
    {

    }

    private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        object o = new Bar();


        if (o is Bar)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("2222222 "+ o.GetType().BaseType);
            if(o.GetType().BaseType is Foo)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("2.5 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.5");
            }
        }
        if (o is object)
            Console.WriteLine("3333333");
    }
```

output is:

```
2222222 VRAM.Form1+Foo`1[System.Single]
3333333
```

I'm trying to check if an `object` is assigned to an instance derived from `Foo` or not. Because in runtime, that object will be a primitive array or a `Foo<float>` or a `Foo<int>` or other `T` primitive types.

Also using `typeof(Foo<>)` for comparison doesn't work. I need only 1-depth checkş of wheter object o is derived from `Foo<>` or not. (I don't want to check all kinds like `Bar` `Biz` `Baz` that are integer double char types and many will be added later so I needed to check in 1line or 2 at most)

Comment: I think what you want is [Type.IsAssignableFrom()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isassignablefrom(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: For that to be compiling, you must *also* have a non-generic `Foo` class lurking around somewhere that you've failed to mention. Types `Foo` and `Foo<T>` aren't related.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever OMG you are right

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`o.GetType().BaseType` returns `Type`, not an instance you can check with `is` or `as`.

A better notation would be:

```
if(o.GetType().BaseType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Foo<>))
```

If you want to check equality of the type. Generally though it is better to use [`Type.IsAssignableFrom`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isassignablefrom.aspx).

Comment: Foo is generic type, so maybe `typeof(Foo<float>)` or `o.GetType().BaseType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Foo<>)`?

Comment: Um, yes @SergeyBerezovskiy

Comment: I think this would work comparing names: `obj.GetType().BaseType.Name == typeof(Foo<>).Name`

Comment: @Pikoh type comparision works, and name comparison will not work here

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy yes, i guess it should be that way. But i just made a test project and Patricks comparision does not return true,while comparing names does...

Comment: isassignable also not working but name comparison works and I assume name is not from another library

Comment: Yes, update code works @PatrickHofman. The problem seems to be the generic foo class

Answer (score 1):

Code as given in the question will not compile unless you have a non-generic `Foo` lying around. In order to use `typeof(Foo<>)`, you should use the `Type.GetGenericTypeDefinition` [MSDN - Type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getgenerictypedefinition(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
if(o.GetType().BaseType is Foo){
    Console.WriteLine("2.5 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.5");
}
```

> I need only 1-depth check of wheter object o is derived from Foo<> or not.

```
if(o.GetType().BaseType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Foo<>)){
    //STUFF
}
```

should work